# MvvmCross Image url binding to handle fallback with default drawable

Tags: android, xamarin, data-binding, mvvmcross

I have a datasource with Images urls, which generally I handle with

```
 <Mvx.MvxImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            local:MvxBind="ImageUrl PosterThumbUrl" />
```

However, some of the records don't have the image (the `PosterThumbUrl` is empty). So, ideally I would like to have something like this:

```
 <Mvx.MvxImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            local:MvxBind="ImageUrl DefaultImage(PosterThumbUrl, 'back_no_image.png')" />
```

(I.e., in case if the url is empty, then to place the drawable fallback image).

From what I saw, I need to create the Data Converter, but I don't know how to handle both within the DataConverter: the default image (auto)-loading as well as manual @drawable image handling.

What I came up with is (inside of the Data Converter in case if the url is empty):

```
            return BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(topActivity.Activity.Resources,  GetResourceId(defaultImage, "drawable", topActivity));

            // otherwise
            return base.Convert(value, targetType, parameter, culture);
```

But it's not handling the default url loading in that case.

So, any thoughts? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with a `ValueConverter`

https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/fundamentals/value-converters

---

Since `ImageUrl` is of type string we will be using a value converter that returns a string `MvxValueConverter<string, string>`.

```
public class StringValueConverter : MvxValueConverter<string, string>
{
    protected override string Convert(string value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null || value == string.Empty)
            return parameter as string;

        return value;
    }
}
```

Property `parameter` holds the default value set within your layout file:

```
 <Mvx.MvxImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        local:MvxBind="ImageUrl StringValue(PosterThumbUrl, 'back_no_image.png')" />
```